# Any way to get the Lua debug interpreter to act more like the interactive interpreter?

Tags: lua, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

I love the convenience of the shorthand '=' in Lua's interactive interpreter.  I also like how the ii prints out returns.  Is there any way to get this functionality inside the debug interpreter?

ii REPL

```
a = 3
= a
> 3
```

debug mode

```
a = 3
print(a)
> 3
```

Yes it's not that hard to type print(a), but muscle memory makes me type =a every time, and it can get annoying after a while.

Comment: I assume you are looking for a way to do this that doesn't involve building your own customize lua?

Comment: Debug mode has more serious inconvenience: it does not allow you to enter a multi-line statement.  Probably, it would be better to write your own `debug.debug` implementation (in Lua, not in C).

Comment: Etan - yes, if possible  @Egor - typically in debug mode i'm just peaking at values not writing definitions, so writing occasional short one-liners doesn't bother me at all.

Comment: Probably you can do p = print. So now its shorter p(a)

Comment: Could you write a wrapper? Read strings from console with `read()`, compare them against specific pattern - `=<whatever>` - and depending on comparsion result, either evaluate them with `loadstring(str)` or `print(loadstring(str))`.